# Apache POI: Why am I getting a null pointer exception with Cell.getCellType() within an if statement that doesn't occur if the cell is null?

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, xssf

I am creating a Groovy script to export tables from an .xlsm file to a .csv file including formulas when appropriate (rather than generated data). When the script calls .getCellType() on the current cell I get a null pointer exception, even though this functionality occurs within an if statement that tests whether the cell is null.

I have tried replacing the

```
if(cell != null)
```

condition with

```
if(cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK)
```

to no avail.

The code and full error message are below.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy

    @Grab(group = 'org.apache.poi', module = 'poi', version = '4.1.0')
    @Grab(group = 'org.apache.poi', module = 'poi-ooxml', version = '4.1.0')

    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*


    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook("input.xlsm")

    FormulaEvaluator fe = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter()
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.csv"), true, "UTF-8")
    byte[] bom = [(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF]
    out.write(bom)

    for (Sheet sheet : wb){
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            boolean firstCell = true
            for(Cell cell : row){
                if (! firstCell) out.print(',')
                if ( cell != null ) {
                    if (fe != null) cell = fe.evaluateInCell()
                    String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
                    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                        value = "=" + value
                    }
                    out.print(value)
                }

                firstCell = false
            }
            out.println()
        }
    }
```

Error Message:

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method 
getCellType() on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke method getCellType() on null object
at ExcelToCSV.run(ExcelToCSV.groovy:28)
```

My expectation is that in the case that the current cell is not null, if the cell is evaluated to contain a formula, the string output to the .csv file will have an "=" appended to the beginning of it, otherwise it will simply output the string representing the value within the cell.

I am unfortunately having problems with my IDE skipping over breakpoints and currently I am unable to step through the code or view the variable values, which is a separate issue I am also working on. Until I get that resolved, I am hoping someone is able to point out what I might be missing.

Comment: You need to check if the cell is null *before* calling any methods on it, eg `getCellType`

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing within the if statement where the method call resides, or am I missing something? As I said its been a challenge trying to debug without being able to set breakpoints.

Comment: Why using [FormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateInCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-)? Most times this is not what one would want. Remove the line `if (fe != null) cell = fe.evaluateInCell()` Then do `String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, fe)` instead. And, if you want the formula string with leading `=`, then `if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) value = "=" + cell.getCellFormula()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to `cell` after the null check, but before you call a `cell` method.  That assignment must be a null value.

`evaluateInCell` takes an argument of type `Cell`, so if you replace your line

```
if (fe != null) cell = fe.evaluateInCell()
// cell == null
```

with

```
if (fe != null) cell = fe.evaluateInCell(cell)
```

then you get what the javadocs say you should get, which is the unchanged cell for simple values or the formula result for formulas.

I think you will also find that the Cell type will change to reflect the type of the value returned by the formula evaluation, so your test for `CellType.FORMULA` will always be false.